# Adicionar barra no fim da URL com Htaccess

Tags: apache, htaccess

Estou tendo um problema com meu `.htaccess`, pois antes usava `.htm` no final agora que quero por barra não consigo alterar.

Uso com fim `.htm` *query string*:

```
##### Url Dinamica ###################################
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

# Exibe a pagina com a extensao em .htm
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-]+)\.htm$ index.php?tag=$1 [qsappend]

</ifModule>
```

Tentei usar

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-]+)\$ index.php?tag=$1/ [qsappend]
```

Mas gera erro e não abre normal

Comment: Boa tarde, qual erro é gerado?

Comment: Está indo para 404

Comment: Já tentou colocar sem nada? Sem a barra, somente o ^([A-Za-z-]+)$

Answer (score 1):

Tente com essa regex `^([A-Za-z-]+)\\\.htm$`.

> `\\` para verificar `\` literal (case sensitive) e
>   `\.` para verificar `.` literal (case sensitive)